# How to use weight when importing from a file?

Tags: python, file

This is my programm, by weightList I want it to use the weights defined in my .csv file. But it gives me the error: ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population

```
    with open(f"{file}", "r") as f:
    for i in f:
        list1 = i.split(",")
        idList = list1[0]
        weightList = random.choices(list1, weights=(list1[6]))
```

How do it fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a sample line from the file (and print len(list1) )

Comment: ID,Entity Name,Size,Zone,Metric,Filename,Weight,,,

Comment: print(len(list1)) is 10 for all lines

Answer (score 2):

The `weight` parameter should also be a `list` with the length of the `list1`.
You are just giving the `weight` one element (`list1[6]`).
You should give a list of `weights`.
for example if the list has 8 elements such as `ID`, `Entity` , `Name` , `Size`, `Zone` , `Metric` , `FileName` , `Weight`. You have to give the `weight` argument a list with length of `8`, for instance: `[1,3,5,2,1,3,2,1]`

```py
weights = [1,3,5,2,1,3,2,1]
weightList = random.choices(list1, weights=weights)
```

---

Update based on your comment below:

> from the file I only need the `ID` and the `weight`

As you said; in each line there are `10` elements, and you only need the `ID` and `weight` of each line.
`ID` is the first (index `0`) element and the 8th (index `7`) element from the line, and you can get them using `split()`:

```py
[...]
elements = i.split(",")
ID , weight = elements[0] , elements[7]
[...]
```

Also you've mentioned that:

> in the end the output should be the only the `ID`s based on the `weight`s.

You can make a `dictionary` to hold `ID`s based on their `weight`s. Actually you don't need `random.choices()` at all.

```py
ids_based_on_weights = dict()
with open(f"{file}", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        list1 = line.split(",")
        id, weight = list1[0], list1[7]
        if weight in ids_based_on_weights:
            ids_based_on_weights[weight].append(id)
        else:
            ids_based_on_weights[weight] = [id]

print(ids_based_on_weights)   # output: IDs based on their Weights
```

Comment: thx for the answer. from the file i only need the ID and the weights. in the end the output should be the only the IDs based on the weights. How would i do that?

Comment: I updated the answer. please take a look @John35

Comment: thatk you for your help, but i think i phrased my question wrong. The output should be 4 for different IDs, nothing else. Just 4 numbers. Which ID is outputted should depend on its weight, if the weight is higher the probability is higher that it will be put out. The programm should loop through the file and then choose 4 IDs depending on its weight.

Comment: this programm only outputs the the ID number and its weights. But i want to use the weight to output the IDs. If the weight is higher the probability of the IDs is higher. Hope this makes it more clear :)